# set layout_below of RelativeLayout within a Relative Layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout `@+id/main_layout`. 

Inside the `@+id/main_layout`, I have a TextView `@+id/txt1` and a RelativeLayout `@+id/store`.

For some reason I have to set `android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"` to the inner RelativeLayout `@+id/store` programmatically. How to do that?

Comment: use setLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams); and set your rules using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try adding it like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, idOfTheViewBelow);
```

Of course, use parameters (fill parent etc.) which you need!

Edit: Of course, you don't need to create the `RelativeLayout`, just instantiate your own, and apply the rules you need!